# does reload tabledata affect cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am currently trying to set up my tableview, when its first loaded I call my connection class which in turn calls my parser class then inside my parser class I call a method in my ViewController, which is the original view that is being set up. This method is passed an array which will be used latter.

The method passes the array to an array variable in this ViewController, in this method I then call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

and what I am wanting that to do is reload cellForRowAtIndexPath so that it will go through my logic (if statements) and check `if ([returnedArray count] != 0){` then do its thing.. but the thread never makes it back to this delegate method, which in turn never makes it back to the if statment.

MORE INFO :)

So first of all, when the the ViewController loads

tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is called and sets up my UITableView that all looks perfect, it then calls my NSURLConnection method which connects to my server downloads all of the data and then passes that over to my parser class. From there my parser dose its thing, and everything is fine.

This is what the code looks like in my tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, method

```
//..
 if (indexPath.row == 0){            
            if ([FilterArray count] == 0){
                [cellActivityIndicator startAnimating];
                //-- Start NSURLConnection
                EngineRequests *engineRequests = [[EngineRequests alloc] init];
                [engineRequests initalizePacketVariables];
            }
if ([FilterArray count] != 0){
                [cellActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
                cell.accessoryView = nil; //hides activity indicator

                cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

                UILabel *label1;
                label1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
                label1.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

                UILabel *label2;
                label2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
                label2.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
//...etc
```

Inside my parser class's parserDidEndDocument method I am passing the NSArray back to the MainView.

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"ISCHECKED",@"T"];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

//call method in VieController1 to pass array over
    SearchViewController *searchViewController = [[SearchViewController alloc] init];
    [SearchViewController initFilterArray:filteredArray];


}
```

So then I head back over to my VC1 and the method that I have declared in the .h and then obviously in the .m file

and this is all of the code that I have in it.

```
#pragma - Reciver methods
-(void)initFilterArray:(NSArray*)array
{
    //initalise array variable for use in latter views
    FilterArray = array;

    //reload to make cell white
    [self.tableView reloadData];

//    NSLog(@"%@", FilterArray);
}
```

While debugging the code the thread makes it to this method and runs everything.. if I uncomment that NSLog, it displays my filitered array and everything. However for some reason the reloadData dose not seem to call tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.. I know this because I have debugged it with breakpoints etc.

So... hopefully this added information will help you help me :)

Comment: This should reload the cells that are visible on the screen. Is it not reloading any cells at all?

Comment: no its not reloading any cells i have debugged the method and it never goes to it after that piece of code runs.

Comment: Don't call reloadData when your are simply setting up the view (such as in viewDidLoad). Let the table cell be configured when the cell for the table row is requested.  call reloadData when you table is already displayed and you need to update it

Comment: Are these being called the first time the tableView loads? Are you using a UITableViewController or building your own table? Post more code if possible... it would be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: No they are not the first times they load. It should be the second.. they are called initially when the view loads. I have added more information to hopfully help you help me.

Comment: Are your cells correctly loading data from `FilterArray`? Is `FilterArray` out of scope after the method call to set it/is it nil when cell for row is called?

Comment: I have debugged it further and after the reloadData call the only table delegates that are called are **numberOfSectionsInTableView** and **tableView:numberOfRowsInSection**

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

it will call the delegate methods.
if it isn't, you can check if self.tableView is linked to the tableView you want to reload.

Comment: both datasource and delegate are linked to the tableview inside interface builder...